# Can default access modifier be assigned to an interface in Java?

Tags: java, interface, access-modifiers

In Java, can the access modifier of an interface be default (left blank) or is it always assumed to be *public abstract* if there is no access modifier defined in front of the keyword *interface*?

Comment: [Java Tutorials: Defining an Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceDef.html): *If you do not specify that the interface is public, then your interface is accessible only to classes defined in the same package as the interface.*

Answer (score 0):

If you do not specify that the interface is public, then your interface is accessible only to classes defined in the same package as the interface. Check this [Link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceDef.html) out